# SQL Server datetime to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sqldatatypes

If you have in SQL Server `DATETIME`, what will this be in Oracle?

`DATE`, where you loose the fractional parts of a second or better `TIMESTAMP(3)`?

Comment: That would entirely depend on your needs. If you don't need milliseconds go with `DATE`. If you do - `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: ok, then. its timestamp in this case. Just wondering why Oracle suggests to use date instead? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/apa.htm

Comment: I don't know, probably because in most cases milisecond are irrelevant - here is another document saying Timestamp can also be used - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10405_01/doc/appdev.120/e10379/ss_oracle_compared.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the fractional seconds, you'd use a `TIMESTAMP(3)` (or just a `TIMESTAMP`).  If you don't care about the fractional seconds, you'd use a `DATE`.

Answer (score 2):

From here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm

DATE contains the following

- Year
- Month
- Day
- Hour
- Minute
- Second

Whereas TIMESTAMP will also contain fractional seconds.
With TIMESTAMP(n) you can specify n as a number between 0 and 9 for how many digits of precision, the default is 6.